# Persistent volumes in tails linux for non-sensitive data

Tags: linux

When using [tails linux](https://tails.boum.org/), I am having difficult configuring persistent storage. I run a VMWare VM, and boot off the tails iso, and I have a vmdk configured as attached to the machine. The vmdk volume is formatted ext3 and lives at `/dev/sda5p1`. I'd like to use it to store things like public keys and email addresses so that I don't have to go pull them down every time I fire up the machine again. However, I cannot update the fstab on the iso, and when I go to Applications > System Tools > Configure Persistent Storage, the app complains that I don't have any usb media attached. The vmdk is scsi, of course.

Is there a way to configure tails with a persistent device? Yes, I am aware that tails is *amnesiac*, but I'd just like a way to store non-sensitive data so that I'm not starting up "stateless" every time.

The only workaround I've been able to think of is to have a tarball at an easily-typed/remembered url I can `(cd /tmp; wget -qO - http://foo | tar xvf - )` with. That's tedious, and not quite ideal.

Comment: This question really isn't a programming question, I think your question would be better suited for SuperUser

Comment: Hm. I hadn't thought of that. I believe you are correct. Sorry about that. Is there a simple way to "move" a post from here to there? (…disregard, I just posted it over there, created account, etc. Thanks)

Comment: You can flag the question to be moved, but it is best to just delete this question and then ask on SuperUser

Comment: Yep, did that. Thanks :)

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/669547/269452 <- the question over at SU.